# Issue with writing a algorithmic method in Java with a double return value and parameters

Tags: java

I wrote a method for C++ a couple years ago and am now trying to adopt it to Java. I thought it would be as simple as editing the first line of the method but I was wrong.

The code is the following. UPDATED:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public static double getJD(double y,double m,double d){
    if (m<=2.0){
        y-=1.0;
        m+=12.0;
    }
    double a=floor(y/100.0);
    return (365.25*(y+4716.0))+(30.6001*(m+1))+d+(2.0-a+floor(a/4.0))-1524.5;
}
```

Edit: Eclipse is still freaking out with the compiler errors listed below.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Syntax error on token "-",
>   delete this token jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 7  Java Problem
>   Syntax error on token ";", ? expected jd.java /Elapsed time
>   calc/src  line 3  Java Problem Syntax error on token ")", , expected
>   after this token  jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 2  Java Problem
>   Syntax error on token "double", { expected    jd.java /Elapsed time
>   calc/src  line 1  Java Problem Syntax error on token "double", @
>   expected  jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 1  Java Problem Syntax
>   error on token "double", delete this token    jd.java /Elapsed time
>   calc/src  line 1  Java Problem Syntax error on token "double", invalid
>   ( jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 1  Java Problem Syntax error on
>   tokens, delete these tokens   jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 1  Java
>   Problem Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens   jd.java /Elapsed
>   time calc/src line 4  Java Problem Syntax error on tokens, delete these
>   tokens    jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 6  Java Problem Syntax
>   error, insert ": Expression" to complete Expression   jd.java /Elapsed
>   time calc/src line 7  Java Problem Syntax error, insert ")" to complete
>   SingleMemberAnnotation    jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 7  Java
>   Problem Syntax error, insert "}" to complete
>   MemberValueArrayInitializer   jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 7  Java
>   Problem Syntax error, insert "}" to complete
>   MemberValueArrayInitializer   jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 7  Java
>   Problem Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete
>   EnumHeaderName    jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 7  Java Problem
>   Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete
>   CompilationUnit   jd.java /Elapsed time calc/src  line 7  Java Problem

Comment: Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double) for the Floor operation

Comment: The only problem I see is you have to implement the method 'floor()'. Or use the Math.floor(), as Renato Lochetti said

Comment: Maybe you can't do `--` on a double in Java. Try `y -= 1.0;`

Comment: Have you defined a **class**? You can't write functions at the top level in Java! If your code is literally as you have posted it above, then that is never going to work. Everything in Java must be inside a class.

Comment: @john Haha, thanks! I had a slow moment there for a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Java must be inside a class. This a complete working class containing your code. You may want to add a package declaration as well.

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Utility
{
    public static double getJD(double y,double m,double d){
        if (m<=2.0) {
            y--;
            m+=12.0;
        }
        double a=floor(y/100.0);
        return (365.25*(y+4716.0))+(30.6001*(m+1))+d+(2.0-a+floor(a/4.0))-1524.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rep you if I could. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a static import for java.lang.Math, you need to replace "floor" with "Math.floor".

A static import lets you refer to static members of another class without qualifying their names:

import static java.lang.Math.*;